# Get all files in all subdirectories in a set

Tags: linux, cmake, latex

I have a folder structure like this:

```
chapters
├── a.tex
├── folder1
│   ├── b.tex
│   ├── c.tex
├── d.tex
└── folder2
    ├── e.tex
    ├── f.tex
...
```

I'm basically modifying an existing makefile, how can I load all `.tex` files in the set `parts` without hardcoding all files like this:

```
set(parts
    chapters/a.tex
    chapters/d.tex
    chapters/folder1/b.tex
    chapters/folder1/c.tex
    ...
)
```

I'm using the `parts` set later like this:

```
add_latex_document(output.tex
    INPUTS ${parts}
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to specify source files with GLOB or each file individually in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/is-it-better-to-specify-source-files-with-glob-or-each-file-individually-in-cmak)

Comment: What is wrong with [file(GLOB_RECURSE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934024/multiple-source-directories-for-one-executable-with-cmake)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive CMake search for header and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653738/recursive-cmake-search-for-header-and-source-files)