# CMake adding OpenCV libs out of order

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I need to control the library order during linking, but CMake is doing weird things with OpenCV libs. See the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cvtest)

set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

add_executable(cvtest "test.cpp")

find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED core)
target_link_libraries(cvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS} FOO)
```

When building the resulting makefile, libraries are linked in the following order:

```
libopencv_core.3.4.2.dylib -lFOO
```

All good so far (FOO needs to go last). However, if I add another opencv lib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(cvtest)

set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

add_executable(cvtest "test.cpp")

find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED core highgui)
target_link_libraries(cvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS} FOO)
```

Then the linker recieves libraries in the following order:

```
libopencv_highgui.3.4.2.dylib -lFOO libopencv_videoio.3.4.2.dylib libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.2.dylib libopencv_imgproc.3.4.2.dylib libopencv_core.3.4.2.dylib
```

Importantly, FOO is not last anymore! I tried everything but I cannot make FOO appear at the end of the linking list. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204820/cmake-and-order-dependent-linking-of-shared-libraries

Comment: Thanks @nuzhny, unfortunately this does not fix my problem. I tried both the link orders in `target_link_libraries` and making a list, but as you can see above, cmake is still linking libraries after FOO.