# Linker: Undefined Reference for const C structs which are located in static lib

Tags: c

I've following problem:

Header File "can_settings.h":

```
#ifndef CAN_SETTINGS_H_
#define CAN_SETTINGS_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "can.h"

extern const CAN_InitTypeDef can_initstruct;

extern const CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_acceptall;
extern CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_1;
extern CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_2;


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Source File "can_settings.c":

```
#include "can_settings.h"

const CAN_InitTypeDef can_initstruct = {
#ifdef SYSCLK_FREQ_72MHz
    // APB1_freq = 36 MHz
    /* .CAN_Prescaler = */ 24,
    /* .CAN_Mode = */ CAN_Mode_Normal,
    /* .CAN_SJW = */ CAN_SJW_1tq,
    /* .CAN_BS1 = */ CAN_BS1_8tq,
    /* .CAN_BS2 = */ CAN_BS2_3tq,
#elif defined SYSCLK_FREQ_24MHz
    // APB1_freq = 24 MHz
    /* .CAN_Prescaler = */ 16,
    /* .CAN_Mode = */ CAN_Mode_Normal,
    /* .CAN_SJW = */ CAN_SJW_1tq,
    /* .CAN_BS1 = */ CAN_BS1_8tq,
    /* .CAN_BS2 = */ CAN_BS2_3tq,
#endif
    /* .CAN_TTCM = */ DISABLE,
    /* .CAN_ABOM = */ DISABLE,
    /* .CAN_AWUM = */ DISABLE,
    /* .CAN_NART = */ DISABLE,
    /* .CAN_RFLM = */ DISABLE,
    /* .CAN_TXFP = */ ENABLE,
};

const CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_acceptall = {
    /* .CAN_FilterIdHigh = */ 0x0000,
    /* .CAN_FilterIdLow = */ 0x0000,
    /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = */ 0x0000,
    /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = */ 0x0000,
    /* .CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = */ 0,
    /* .CAN_FilterNumber = */ 0,
    /* .CAN_FilterMode = */ CAN_FilterMode_IdMask,
    /* .CAN_FilterScale = */ CAN_FilterScale_32bit,
    /* .CAN_FilterActivation = */ ENABLE
};

const CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_1 = {
        /* .CAN_FilterIdHigh = */ 0x0000,
        /* .CAN_FilterIdLow = */ CAN_ID_EXT,
        /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = */ 0x14FC << 3,
        /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = */ CAN_ID_EXT,
        /* .CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = */ 0,
        /* .CAN_FilterNumber = */ 0,
        /* .CAN_FilterMode = */ CAN_FilterMode_IdMask,
        /* .CAN_FilterScale = */ CAN_FilterScale_32bit,
        /* .CAN_FilterActivation = */ ENABLE
};

const CAN_FilterInitTypeDef can_filter_2 = {
        /* .CAN_FilterIdHigh = */ 0x0000,
        /* .CAN_FilterIdLow = */ CAN_ID_EXT,
        /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = */ 0x1400 << 3,
        /* .CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = */ CAN_ID_EXT,
        /* .CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = */ 0,
        /* .CAN_FilterNumber = */ 1,
        /* .CAN_FilterMode = */ CAN_FilterMode_IdMask,
        /* .CAN_FilterScale = */ CAN_FilterScale_32bit,
        /* .CAN_FilterActivation = */ ENABLE
};
```

The linker returns undefined reference to 'can_initstruct' can_filter_acceptall' 'can_filter_1' 'can_filter_2'...
The files can_settings.{c, h} are built as a static library and are used in my main application(only C) and in my CAN low level driver (C++).
All static libraries are built before my low level drivers and main application have been built.
With objdump I dumped the static CAN settings library and all the above structs are listed in the .rodata section as it should be.
What I'm doing wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GCC, be sure that you specify the libraries in the correct order. See [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/520162) for a detailed description.

However, if you don't want to bother with the library sequence, simply specify the sequence **twice** instead of just one time. Applied on the accepted answer of the above question, this would mean:

```
gcc prog.o libA.a libB.a libA.a libB.a -o prog.x
```

As an alternative, use the `-Wl,--start-group` `...` `-Wl,--end-group` flags of GCC ([GCC: what are the --start-group and --end-group command line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/gcc-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options)).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
The order you specify object files and libraries is VERY important in GCC!
The linker searches thinks in the order that they appear, so if you have a source file that contains a call to a library function, you need to put it BEFORE the library, or the linker won't know that it has to resolve it. And I did it the wrong way...

Thx eckes for the hint.