# Undefined reference to _kill, _getpid and _sbrk

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm here because I can't solve my problem; in fact I'm making a C project with the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler in Eclipse CDT C/C++ IDE(it's for the STM32 embedded card), and I have implemented PolarSSL to create an HTTPS server :

I saw in many forums that I need to delete the `printf`, `malloc`, `file`, `path` to avoid this error(indeed I'm on an embedded project so these functions are prohibited!). But these errors stay here even if I delete all these functions! So now I don't know how solve these errors, so could you help me please?

Thank you for your help.

```
'Building file: ../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c'
'Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DARP_CACHE_SIZE=4 -D_kill -D_getpid -D_cert -DUSE_IPV4 -DUSE_IPV6 -DNDP_CACHE_SIZE=4 -DHARDWARE_ETH_TX_CRC -DHARDWARE_ETH_RX_CRC -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DUSE_TCP -DHSE_VALUE=25000000 -DSTM32F2XX -DUSE_MII -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/Library_StackIP/Driver_phyter_f2" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/stm32f2xx" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/urts" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/ethernet" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/agilia" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/Service_HttpServeur" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/Library_StackIP" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/include/polarssl" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/include" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1/test_serverweb_v0/src/library" -I"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\CMSIS_V3P00\CMSIS\Include" -I"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\CMSIS_V3P00\Device\ST\STM32F2xx\Include" -I"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\inc" -I"C:\Sebastien\Sujet_1_ServeurWeb\Projet_1\test_serverweb\src\LibrarySSL" -I"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\StdPeriph_Driver\inc" -I"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\STM32_Ethernet\inc" -I"C:\AIM\uOne\F2\inc" -I"C:\AIM\uOne\F2\StdPeriph_Driver\inc" -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -mfloat-abi=softfp -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -MMD -MP -MF".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.d" -MT".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.d" -o ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o" "../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c"
'Finished building: ../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c'

'Building target: test_serverweb_v0'
'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -static -L"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\lib" -L"C:\AIM\uOne\F2\lib" -L"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\StdPeriph_Driver\lib" -L"C:\Program Files\AIM\uOne\Tools\eclipse\..\..\F2\STM32_Ethernet\lib" -L"C:\AIM\uOne\F2\STM32_Ethernet\lib" -L"C:\AIM\uOne\F2\StdPeriph_Driver\lib" -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,-T,../ldscripts/flash.ld,-Map,Debug.map,--gc-sections -o "test_serverweb_v0"  ./src/urts/urts_init.o  ./src/stm32f2xx/startup_stm32f2xx.o ./src/stm32f2xx/system_stm32f2xx.o  ./src/library/aes.o ./src/library/aesni.o ./src/library/arc4.o ./src/library/asn1parse.o ./src/library/asn1write.o ./src/library/base64.o ./src/library/bignum.o ./src/library/blowfish.o ./src/library/camellia.o ./src/library/certs.o ./src/library/cipher.o ./src/library/cipher_wrap.o ./src/library/ctr_drbg.o ./src/library/debug.o ./src/library/des.o ./src/library/dhm.o ./src/library/ecdh.o ./src/library/ecdsa.o ./src/library/ecp.o ./src/library/ecp_curves.o ./src/library/entropy.o ./src/library/entropy_poll.o ./src/library/error.o ./src/library/gcm.o ./src/library/havege.o ./src/library/md.o ./src/library/md2.o ./src/library/md4.o ./src/library/md5.o ./src/library/md_wrap.o ./src/library/memory.o ./src/library/memory_buffer_alloc.o ./src/library/net.o ./src/library/oid.o ./src/library/padlock.o ./src/library/pbkdf2.o ./src/library/pem.o ./src/library/pk.o ./src/library/pk_wrap.o ./src/library/pkcs11.o ./src/library/pkcs12.o ./src/library/pkcs5.o ./src/library/pkparse.o ./src/library/pkwrite.o ./src/library/ripemd160.o ./src/library/rsa.o ./src/library/sha1.o ./src/library/sha256.o ./src/library/sha512.o ./src/library/ssl_cache.o ./src/library/ssl_ciphersuites.o ./src/library/ssl_cli.o ./src/library/ssl_srv.o ./src/library/ssl_tls.o ./src/library/threading.o ./src/library/timing.o ./src/library/version.o ./src/library/x509.o ./src/library/x509_create.o ./src/library/x509_crl.o ./src/library/x509_crt.o ./src/library/x509_csr.o ./src/library/x509write_crt.o ./src/library/x509write_csr.o ./src/library/xtea.o  ./src/agilia/agilia_VC.o ./src/agilia/agilia_VS.o ./src/agilia/agilia_init_uRTS.o ./src/agilia/agilia_login_sha1.o ./src/agilia/agilia_moteur_info.o ./src/agilia/agilia_targetId.o ./src/agilia/agilia_xbin_mem.o  ./src/Service_HttpServeur/AFS.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/AgiliaGV.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/Base64.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/HtmlPage.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/HtmlPageDynamic.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/Http.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/HttpServer.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/HttpUsers.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/MoteurHTTP.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/StdAfx.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/UTF8.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/WebSite.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/divers.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/httpd.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/mime.o ./src/Service_HttpServeur/sgf_sdcard.o  ./src/Library_StackIP/Driver_phyter_f2/drv_buffer.o ./src/Library_StackIP/Driver_phyter_f2/drv_mac.o ./src/Library_StackIP/Driver_phyter_f2/drv_phyter_f2.o ./src/Library_StackIP/Driver_phyter_f2/drv_stats.o  ./src/Library_StackIP/arp.o ./src/Library_StackIP/hntonh.o ./src/Library_StackIP/icmp.o ./src/Library_StackIP/icmpv6.o ./src/Library_StackIP/interface_ethernet.o ./src/Library_StackIP/ipv4.o ./src/Library_StackIP/ipv6.o ./src/Library_StackIP/sck_api.o ./src/Library_StackIP/tcp.o ./src/Library_StackIP/udp.o  ./src/config_user.o ./src/ethernet_init.o ./src/hardware_init.o ./src/main.o ./src/peripherals_config.o ./src/ressources.o ./src/ssl_init_uRTS.o ./src/systickDelay.o ./src/timer_uRTS.o  ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o    -lservice_strformat -lagcomethernet -ltest_syscalls_v2 -lagcore -lagstr -lagtrycatch -lagvariables -lcrc16_soft -lcrc32_f2 -lsha1_soft -lagmetadebug -lflash_f2 -ldrv_phyter_f2 -lservice_horodateur -lservice_httpServeur -lservice_socket -lservice_STM32 -lsysirq -lsysrtc_f2 -lurts -lurtscore -ltrap12 -ltrap12core -lsystime -lsystick -lstm32_stdperiph_driver -lstm32_ethernet -lRessources
c:/program files/aim/uone/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m\libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_kill'
c:/program files/aim/uone/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m\libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): undefined reference to `_getpid'
c:/program files/aim/uone/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
aim-make: *** [test_serverweb_v0] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Does the platform have an OS, or is your application intended to be "freestanding" ?

Comment: thank you for your answers. i'm not compiling on command line : i'm in windows and i use the eclipse environment. the stm32 card didn't have an OS like i said just below ! so we can say that my application intended to be "freestanding" ! so these OS functions are useless for me... but i can't separate them easier...

Comment: The error messages are *plain text* - why do you need to post a picture!?

Comment: You need to figure out where those functions are referenced - that should be clear in the error messages, but if not recursive grep is your friend.  If they are referenced in library code you build but never use, perhaps you need a "-Wl,--gc-sections" build flag to cause the linker to prune unused code.

Comment: sorry clifford, i mean : give a copy of the screen of these error messages in eclipse ! i write here the 3 error messages :

Comment: @user3463977:  Don't add the error messages as comments!  Update your question.

Comment: Add the complete build log (to the question), not just the error messages - we need to see how the linker was invokes at least.

Comment: i update my first message with the "cross gcc linker invoking" ! what do you think about please ? regards, sebastien.

Comment: i add a typical message of my console for the "cross GCC compiler invoking" too : of course the message is the same for the other "building file" ! thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [forum](https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread2449#threadId2453) try adding:

> -specs=nosys.specs

Answer (score 1):

I understand that these are OS functions necessary to use newlib (a standard c lib implementation). On a system which doesn't provide them (as @wildplasser said: no OS?) they apparently need to be defined explicitly. Perhaps this link helps: http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib. I got there from http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/using-newlib-in-arm-bare-metal-programs/.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer. i'm working on windows 7, and my stm32 board didn't have an OS : so i flash my web server inside it. your 2nd document seems  to be useful, thanks ! but in fact about my project, i don't need to use these functions like printf, etc... so i would delete these functions, but i don't know if it's possible for polarSSL ( otherwise i'm going to use newlib, but does it work on windows please ? ) thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "delete" anything in Newlib, and neither should you - and I don't think it will help - I wonder where you read that?

You need to provide the syscall stubs, although many of them can be empty functions, or at least return the *error* state, in case someone or something does inadvertently call them - they are to do with process control, memory allocation and stream I/O.  These are almost certainly referenced indirectly by the third-party code you are using.

If you build Newlib as a static library, it will only link the code that is necessary to resolve symbols in your code, so if you are getting undefined references then you are calling something that depends on them.

What you should not do is compile and link the Newlib code directly to your application code - that will link a large amount of unused code and require you to supply otherwise unused stubs.

Comment: I think the intent was to not use them at all, and remove the need for them to be resolved as dependencies - hopefully not be deleting them from the library, but rather by not using any functionality which requires them.

Comment: firstly thank you for your answers ! newlib has a linux dependance, isn't it ? like sys/ librairies ; in this website just below, we have newlib_stubs.c which have #include sys/stats.h, etc...so it will not work, isn't it ? ( i'm on windows ) http://stm32discovery.nano-age.co.uk/open-source-development-with-the-stm32-discovery/getting-newlib-to-work-with-stm32-and-code-sourcery-lite-eabi

Comment: moreover, if i absolutely need to use newlib, do i need to insert all the newlib source, like in this website just below, in my C project  ? http://stm32discovery.nano-age.co.uk/open-source-development-with-the-stm32-discovery/getting-newlib-to-work-with-stm32-and-code-sourcery-lite-eabi

Comment: No, Newlib does not have Linux dependencies.  It has a set of syscall stubs that you must provide to map the library to your system (Whether it uses a GPOS, RTOS or bare-metal).  In the link you posted, read the comment above the `_fstat()` function - the naming is used for consistency with POSIX and the file itself is provided with the package discussed in the article (although it is not clear to me that that package is available for download).

Comment: You have two choices.  You can build a static libc.a library from the Newlib source that includes your syscall stubs, or you can build it without the syscalls, and compile an link the syscall code with your application.  The latter is probably preferable if you do not intend to fully implement all the stubs, and you want a single library that will work on any Cortex-M based processor.  If you already have a Newlib libc.a, then you clearly need to do the latter in any case unless you want to rebuild the library.

Comment: Minimal implementations of all the syscall stubs are provided in the [Newlib documentation](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls).  They are very simple.  I recommend that you at least implement `sbrk` since third party libraries you might use may expect a working heap.

Comment: i took the _kill, _getpid and _sbrk, create a static library .a and link it with my project but it doesn't work... ( i had the .d related too )

Comment: Post the *complete* build log - update the question do not add as comments.  These functions are clearly not being linked, so you need to post all linker and compiler diagnostic information to get a diagnosis.  I suggest you simplify things and add the syscalls source to your project rather than a separate static library.  If you have a separate static library for syscalls and libc.a, you will need to ensure that the syscalls library appears in the link order ahead of libc.a, or use [*grouping*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/gcc-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options)

Comment: I have a `Make` project with similar issue. On my machine the code compiles. However, my colleague can cot compile on his machine - `undefined reference to _getpid` error is returned. Does anyone have a clue as to why this could be the case: i.e. why the code compiles on one machine but not on the other?

Comment: @mercury0114 SO is not a discussion forum. If you have a question, post a question. By posting a comment, the only people likely to see it on a 6 year old answer are me and the OP. Also your problem is most likely not that similar to this issue where the syscalls were not implemented. Rather, you are clearly not linking in the same object code or libraries across the two systems. Possibly there are dependencies on environment variables that differ across the two. A text comparison of the build log from a clean build may help identify differences.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile with option `-nostartfiles` when you are compiling to MCUs.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was compiling with C++ and turning exceptions off solved my problem.
Add `-fno-exceptions` to your compile flags. You may also want to turn off [Run Time Type Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) (RTTI) as well, i.e. `-fno-rtti`.

`CPPFLAGS += -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti`

Comment: not related to C++. C does not have exceptions or RTTI.