# I cannot load a texture from a file (SFML c++)

Tags: c++, sfml

When I use the function .loadFromFile(), i get the following error:

undefined reference to `sf::Texture::loadFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, sf::Rect const&)'|

I have already tried different versions of SFML, and according to their website I'm using the correct one.

Here is my setup:
codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe => download for codeblocks
SFML-2.4.2-windows-gcc-4.9.2-tdm-32-bit => SFML I am using

Here are my settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

in the compiler tab

[image]

in the linker tab

[image]

The linking should be ok, as all the other SFML functions work. I have read that it could be because of SFML being compiled by a different compiler than mine? How can I check that? Is it something else that causes this problem?

here is the code :

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main () {

Texture texun;
    texun.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\j_hyl\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\Webdev\Apps\\Drive\\sprite.bmp");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php says the `sf::Texture` is part of the `graphics` module, do you link to that?

Comment: yes. You can't see it on the picture but yes i linked to it. I can use RectangleShape and it's methods for example, without any problem

Comment: As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994820/issue-with-linking-order-of-the-libraries the order of the linker input matters, can you try to move the graphics module down in the linker arguments?

Comment: Figured it out! Wrong SFML version (using 2.4.2 instead of 2.5.1). Thx for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to link to `sfml-graphics.lib` or if your configuration is debug you have to link with `sfml-graphics-d.lib`  and you have to copy the `sfml-graphics-2.dll` and `sfml-graphics-d-2.dll`(if debugging conf.) to the folder where your executable is