# How do you pass the --start-group and --end-group flags to gcc when using scons?

Tags: gcc, scons

In scons, how do you implement the --start-group and --end-group gcc flags? These should wrap a particular set of LIBS, but I couldn't find a PREFIX/SUFFIX option that wraps the entire (or partial set of) input to LIBS.

In case you're wondering what gcc flags I'm talking about, read more here:

[GCC: what are the --start-group and --end-group command line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/gcc-what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options)

Comment: Have you searched the scons user group mailing list archives. I think this has been covered.  It's not simple, but can be done.   Usually this means you have recursive dependencies and need this to unravel that mess... Is that the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that there is no built in prefix/suffix for this wrapper. The command line options specifying the list of libraries passed to the link command is computed based on the `LIBS` environment variable and stored in the `_LIBFLAGS` environment variable. `_LIBFLAGS` is then used as a part of the complete linker command line.

The defaults, defined in *Tool/link.py* in the SCons library, look something like:

```
env['LINKCOM']  = '$LINK -o $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $__RPATH $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
env['_LIBFLAGS']='${_stripixes(LIBLINKPREFIX, LIBS, LIBLINKSUFFIX, LIBPREFIXES, LIBSUFFIXES, __env__)}'
```

Assuming that you want to wrap the entire set of libraries, then in your environment, you can edit either the `LINKCOM` or the `_LIBFLAGS` variables to add the options:

```
# SConstruct

env = Environment(
    CC = 'gcc',
    LINKCOM = '$LINK -o $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $__RPATH $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS -Wl,--start-group $_LIBFLAGS -Wl,--end-group'
)

#env.Prepend(_LIBFLAGS="-Wl,--start-group ")  # the trailing space is required
#env.Append(_LIBFLAGS=" -Wl,--end-group")     # the leading space is required
env.Program('foo', ['foo.c'], LIBS='m')
```

I think editing `LINKCOM` is a little less invasive. In my trivial example, this generates:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o -Wl,--start-group -lm -Wl,--end-group
scons: done building targets.
```

If you want to group just a subset of libraries, then you'll have to use separate `LIBS` variables for the "wrapped" and "unwrapped" libraries and duplicate the `_LIBFLAGS` function in a separate variable appended to `LINKCOM`.