# Linking shared libraries with gcc on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I need to compile and, most importantly, link a `C` program that uses a proprietary `function` present in a shared library file. Because of lack of communication with the previous development team, there is no proper documentation. I declared a function prototype (because I know the number and type of arguments):

```
int CustomFunction(unsigned char *in, int size);
```

Since that function name can be grepped from `/customlibs/libcustom.so`, I tried to compile the code and link it like this:

```
gcc -L/customlibs testing.c -o testing -lcustom
```

Which throws a few error messages looking like this:

```
/customlibs/libcustom.so: undefined reference to `AnotherCustomFunction'
```

Obviously, I need to tell linker to include other libraries as well, and, to make things worse, they need to be in certain order. I tried exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, using `-Wl,-rpath=`, `-Wl,--no-undefined` and `-Wl,--start-group`. Is there an easy way to give the linker all the `.so` files without the proper order?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution (or a workaround) to my problem: adding `-Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols`, which turns errors to warnings. Note that this works only if you are ABSOLUTELY certain your function does not depend on the symbols mentioned in `undefined refernce to:` messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add them on the command line is a way to do it.  Something like this below.  The LD_LIBRARY_PATH tells gcc where to look for libraries, but you still need to say what libraries to include.

gcc -L/customlibs testing.c -o testing -lcustom -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3

Comment: I tried that, and it complains about more undefined references

Comment: Ulrik, Which references? You should add more libs... And you may try `ldd` command on every shared library to extract which libraries it depend on, and then use [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) or just try to add them all to the link command ([between `-(` and `-)` option pair](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651895/196561)).

Comment: When I add all the shared libraries with `-Wl,--start-group -lcustom1 -lcutom2 ... -Wl,--end-group` I get even more messages like `/customlibs/libcustom.so: undefined reference to `AnotherCustomFunction'`

Answer (score 0):

You should also include all the header files of your shared library by adding the -I option of gcc, for example : `gcc [...] -I/path/to/your/lib/header/files [...]`