# Cannot link against .so file - undefined

Tags: c, ld

I have a very short sample code that I wanted to run, using an external library, but I cannot get my code to work with that library.

What I have is a .h and a .so file (I am coming from Windows, there I would expect a .dll and a .lib, am I missing a necessary file?)

```
(testlib) aroth@CORPLAP1378:~/dev/testlib/Python/PyBind_Module$ gcc sample.c -o sample -L/home/aroth/dev/testlib/Libraries -lm -ltestlib
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aroth/dev/testlib/Libraries/libtestlib.so: undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aroth/dev/testlib/Libraries/libtestlib.so: undefined reference to `sqrtf'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aroth/dev/testlib/Libraries/libtestlib.so: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aroth/dev/testlib/Libraries/libtestlib.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my output from gcc, so I am kinda confused because I did in fact include the math library there (`-lm`), so why does the .so complain? If I compile without linking against the .so file, I get

```
sample.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `libEntry'
```

with the linker telling me it doesn't know the entry point to a function.

I don't fully understand what I am doing wrong here. I would expect a .a or .o file to link against, not a .so

Comment: Is the library `libtestlib.so` compiler correctly with `-lm`?

Comment: What do you mean? The documentation of the testlib I have is, to call it frank, lackluster. How libtestlib.so was compiled, I cannot tell. Would it have to include the math library when itself was compiled?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082816/linking-shared-libraries-with-gcc-on-linux

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, sorry to be so vague...

Comment: Try changing the order of the `-l` options: `-ltestlib -lm`.

Comment: That worked. Ha, I was expecting I needed to link the math first, so its known in the testlib

Comment: Linking is kind of backwards in that respect. You don't have to make its contents known first. Instead, you make the needed externals known in the calling modules, and then it loads only those when it finds them in the library.