# How to handle c++ library circular dependency in Bazel?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, bazel

Does Bazel have a feature similar to gcc -( archives -) or --start-group archives --end-group [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/gcc-what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options) to handle circular dependencies among libraries ?

Alternatively, does Bazel have a feature using which we can use this gcc feature in Bazel ? For example, using something like CCFLAGS ?

Answer (score 2):

It is considered by many that it is better to avoid circular dependencies in the first place.

Suppose you have two files, where `a.cc` #includes `b.h` and `b.cc` #includes `a.h`:

```
cc_library(
  name="a",
  srcs=["a.cc"],
  hdrs=["a.h"],
  deps=[":b"],  # a.cc #includes b.h
)

cc_library(
  name="b",
  srcs=["b.cc"],
  hdrs=["b.h"],
  deps=[":a"],  # b.cc #includes a.h
)
```

`bazel` will complain about a circular dependency.

If you own all the code in question, the more straightforward way to avoid these circular dependencies is to reshuffle your source code and bazel packages to avoid the dependency in the first place.

One strategy here would be to refactor out the common stuff into a third "core" library `c` that depends on neither `a` nor `b`:

```
cc_library(
  name="a",
  srcs=["a.cc"],
  hdrs=["a.h"],
  deps=[":c"],  # a.cc #includes c.h
)

cc_library(
  name="b",
  srcs=["b.cc"],
  hdrs=["b.h"],
  deps=[":c"],  # b.cc #includes c.h
)

cc_library(
  name="c",
  srcs=["c.cc"],
  hdrs=["c.h"],
)
```

Another strategy is to have some kind of build step to copy `a.h` and `b.h` to some "public headers" folder (which itself doesn't depend on anything else). This removes the file-level circular dependency, but semantically, the source code still has a circular dependency between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't own the libraries, you'll have to wait until [cc_import-kind-of-rule](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hK2mWl3TYNL9oJYX_S020TKkXZvBw1aBoYERvTHVyfg/edit?ts=597b4f3d#) is implemented. Also see [issue #818](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/818). I'm not aware of a workaround for the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two classes A and B as outlined below that are valid C++, and you are having trouble setting up build rules. You have a few options for modifying either you build rules or refactoring your code.

class_a.h

```cpp
#ifndef class_a_h__
#define class_a_h__
// Forward declare class A
class A;

// Include dependencies here in case they require class A.
#include "class_b.h"

// Actually declare class A
class A {
 void SetB(B* b);
 // other fields and methods that may use b
};
#endif // class_a_h__
```

class_b.h

```cpp
#ifndef class_b_h__
#define class_b_h__
// Forward declare class B
class B;

// Include dependencies here in case they require class B
#include "class_a.h"

// Actually declare class B
class B {
 public:
  void SetA(A* a);
  // other fields and methods that may use a
};
#endif // class_b_h__
```

### Option 1: Declare libA and libB without declaring their interdependency.

The magic here is including the other class header in the dependent class lib's srcs. You can make one depend on the other but not in both directions.

#### Pros:

- No need to refactor the source.
- Minimal work to refactor the BUILD file so good for temporary debugging aids.

#### Cons:

- Bazel won't know why the linker can't find missing symbols if some_other_lib doesn't depend on both lib_a and lib_b.

BUILD.bzl

```
cc_library(name="lib_a",srcs=["class_a.cc", "class_b.h"],hdrs=["class_a.h"])
cc_library(name="lib_b",srcs=["class_b.cc", "class_a.h"],hdrs=["class_b.h"])
cc_library(name="some_other_lib",srcs=["other.cc"],hdrs=["other.h"],deps=[":lib_a",":lib_b"])
```

### Option 2: Create one library that holds both class A and class B.

I have mixed feelings about this one, but it's probably what I would suggest by default. Because of the cyclic dependency you should never be using one lib without the other so I think it's ok to combine them into a single target.

#### Pros:

- Accurately captures dependency graph.
- No need to refactor the source.

#### Cons:

- Less granular dependency graph. i.e. You can not depend on just one of the libs.
- If your setup is complicated enough this could turn a Makefile with obvious dependencies into a single cc_library of all your code.

BUILD.bzl

```
cc_library(name="lib_a_and_b",srcs=["class_a.cc", "class_b.cc"],hdrs=["class_a.h", "class_b.h"])
cc_library(name="some_other_library",srcs=["other.cc"],hdrs=["other.h"],deps=[":lib_a_and_b"])
```

### Option 3: Extract base class(es).

This can be an option, but is just always complicated for any real world scenario. Do you make class C that takes A and B as parameters and then make usages of A and B use C instead or some other permutation depending on how you need them to work. I'm pretty sure this just isn't possible for something like an event bus that knows about event handlers and the handlers need to know about the bus to send other events.

#### Pros:

- Possibly results in better code.
- No build "magic".

#### Cons:

- Not trivial.
- Not always possible.
- Might result in worse code.
- Requires modifying the source code.

### Option 3a: Combine class A and class B into a single class.

If this is an option for you, then it is a more simple refactor option. The classes are obviously already related. Maybe they make more sense as a single class.

#### Pros:

- Trivial refactor
- No build "magic"

#### Cons:

- Not always possible.
- Might violate your team's coding principles.
- Requires modifying the source code.