# libintl.h file not found with g++ for vertica instructions

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions, vertica

I am trying to fallow [Vertica instructions](https://www.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/UserDefinedFunctions/CompilingYourUDF.htm) to compile their sample file, but getting the below error:

> ./include/Vertica.h:62:10: fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found

I am running this script:

```
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I ./include -I -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o MyUDF.so StringTokenizer.cpp ./include/Vertica.cpp
```

I have also been trying to install getText using homebrew and made the following exports:

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include"
```

Any idea how to resolve my error?

**Edit**

When manually providing -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include getting new error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libintl_gettext", referenced from:
      gettext(char const*) in Vertica-9f5253.o
```

**Edit 2: Solved**

This is the solution that worked out for me:

```
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -L /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I ./include -lintl -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o MyUDF.so StringTokenizer.cpp ./include/Vertica.cpp
```

What helped was the addition of `-lintl`

Comment: Did you find `libintl.h` when searching your machine? If not you probably need to install another dependency.

Comment: have you tried **g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I ./include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o MyUDF.so StringTokenizer.cpp ./include/Vertica.cpp -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib**

Comment: @138 yeah, now I have a new problem. Updated the question

Comment: How about now? **g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I./include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC StringTokenizer.cpp ./include/Vertica.cpp -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib  -o MyUDF.so** you might have to check/rearrange the order of the args.

Comment: @138 Same, I also been trying to play with the order a bit more

Comment: @IlyaGazman Yeah, the order matters. Sorry I can't help much from here, beyond me. I would also make sure that gettext has all the correct binaries and/or headers... Good luck

Comment: @IlyaGazman You can use the `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` linker flags to avoid the need for getting the order right, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options) also.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Getting: `unknown option: --start-group` when running: `g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -Wl,--start-group -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I ./include -Wl,--end-group -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o MyUDF.so StringTokenizer.cpp ./include/Vertica.cpp`