# GCC doesn't find functions in lib

Tags: c, gcc, lib

I have a C file, which uses multiple lib files.
I am trying to compile the file in the following way:

```
gcc -o myprogram main.c list.lib filelib.lib
```

However, when trying to compile I get a bunch of `undefined reference` errors of all the `lib` functions that I'm using.

I came accross a solution on the internet and tried the following:

```
gcc -o myprogram main.c -l list -l filelib
```

Now I get the following errors:

```
cannot find -llist
cannot fint -lfilelib
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Both the libs were originally created using Visual Studio 2019, Release mode x64.
I am using Windows 10, 64 bits architecture.
In the folder I'm running gcc from I have the following files:

```
main.c
list.lib (copied from VS)
list.h (copied form VS)
filelib.lib (copied from VS)
filelib.h (copied from VS)
```

In my lib code in VS I made sure the functions have c-linkage:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define C_LINKAGE extern "C"
#else
#define C_LINKAGE
#endif
```

(each declared function in both the libs starts with the C_LINKAGE macro)

Comment: What functions are you getting errors about? And where (in which libraries) are they defined? And what are the library dependencies? Which library depends on which other library (because order matter when you link with libraries).

Comment: Order does indeed matter, and if libraries depend on each other, you should add the `start-group` / `end-group`option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options

Comment: filelib depends on list, and main.c depends on both

Comment: I pretty much get an error for each and every lib function I try to use

Comment: Then you should change the order. If library `A` depends on library `B`, then `A` needs to come *first* on the command-line.

Comment: When using ```start-group``` and ```end-group``` I get the following error: ```gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--start-group'; did you mean '--stdarg-opt'?```

Comment: Tried doing the following: ```gcc -o myprogram -l filelib -l list main.c```. Still get the same ```cannot find``` error

Comment: Try without the `-l` options. If you use the `-l` option and the libraries are not in a "standard" location you need to tell the linker where the libraries are with the `-L` option. And the source file should be *first* since it depends on both libraries. I.e. `gcc -o myprogram main.c filelib.lib list.lib` (if both libraries are in the current directory).

Comment: Now I get all the undefined references again

Comment: Please add a directory listing **as text** that shows what files are present. What is your OS? Did you create the libraries yourself? If yes, show the commands you used to build the libraries. Please [edit] your question to add the requested information, don't use comments to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .lib files are MSVC specific, gcc can not handle them, gcc can handle .a libraries or dll's (on windows)

If you want to use gcc, rebuild the libraries with gcc, or let MSVC create DLL's.

Or stick to microsoft and use MSVC for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just put "-l:liblist.lib" instead of "-llist" when the suffix is not ".a". That should solve the "Not found" issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a BIG thanks to @Harkaitz for this hint.

I spent several days to figure out why GCC (arm cross compile on Windows) was not able to find my libs in group. I wish those spelling issues to be more documented somewhere...

Basically the ':' in between '-l' and 'lib.a' was solving the issue, like this:

```
-L./my_path_to_libs -Xlinker --start-group -l:libmain.a -Xlinker --end-group
```

Depending on arm gcc verzion, -Xlinker could be -Wl