# How to use `--start-group` and `--end-group` in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, g++

Is it possible to use CMake to enclose a target's libraries in `--start-group`/`--end-group` without manually writing the argument string into `target_link_options`?

**Background:** I'm having [library ordering issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc/409470#409470) when linking a C++ executable to a list of libraries (using g++ 7.5.0). I recently learned about the [`--start-group` and `--end-group` options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options) in gcc/g++ that allow for repeated searching of archives. I would like to enable these options when using CMake to generate my build files.

Given a list of target library names (e.g. `target_link_libraries(myTarget mylibrary1 mylibrary2 ${MY_VARIABLE_LIST_OF_LIBRARIES} ...)`), is it possible to enclose all those libraries within `--start-group`/`--end-group` without having to manually type out the arguments as in `target_link_options(myTarget PUBLIC "--start-group -lmylibrary1 -lmylibrary2 ... --end-group")`? (I'd especially like to avoid having to track down the contents of `${MY_VARIABLE_LIST_OF_LIBRARIES}"` to manually add `-l` to all libraries included in that variable.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CMake 3.24 introduces [LINK_GROUP](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:LINK_GROUP) generator expression, which allows to group libraries in `target_link_libraries` command for adding some *feature* on that group. One of the group features is RESCAN, which effectively adds `--start-group`/`--end-group` for a GNU compiler:

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget
  PRIVATE # or any other keyword
  mylibrary1 mylibrary2 # These libraries will be linked normally
  "$<LINK_GROUP:RESCAN,${MY_VARIABLE_LIST_OF_LIBRARIES}>" # These libraries will be grouped
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_GROUP_USING_<FEATURE>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_GROUP_USING_FEATURE.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_LINK_GROUP_USING_%3CFEATURE%3E):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_GROUP_USING_cross_refs_SUPPORTED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_GROUP_USING_cross_refs
  "LINKER:--start-group"
  "LINKER:--end-group"
)
target_link_libraries(
  myTarget
  "$<LINK_GROUP:cross_refs,your_lib1, external_lib>"
)
```